# Как сделать пробел?

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Суть моей программы в том, чтобы введенный с клавиатуры строки объединяются друг с другом. Как сделать так, чтобы между ними был пробел? Если вводя новую строку изначально не поставить пробел то строки будут объединяться без пробела. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  namespace EXAMPLE_FOR_FOREACH
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Каждая введенная вами строка " +"будет добавляться в предложение, "+
                "пока вы не введете EXIT или QUIT");
     

   //Запрашиваем пользовательский ввод и соединяем вводимые 
        //пользователем фразы в единое целое, пока не будет введена
        //команда завершения работы
            string sentence = String.Empty;
            for (; ; )
            {
                //Получение очередной строки
                Console.WriteLine("Введите строку");
                string line = Console.ReadLine();
                //Выход при вводе команды завершения

                string[] terms = { "EXIT", "exit", "QUIT", "quit" };
                //Сравниваем введенную строку с командами выхода
                bool quitting = false;
                foreach (string term in terms)
                {
                     //Прекращение цикла при совпадении
                     if (String.Compare(line, term)==0)
                    {
                        quitting = true;
                    }
                }
                if (quitting==true)
                {
                    break;
                }
                //В противном случае добавление введеного к строке
                sentence = String.Concat(sentence, line);
                //Обратная связь
                Console.WriteLine("\n Вы ввели: " + sentence);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n Получилось: \n " + sentence);
            //Ожидаем подтверждения пользвателя
            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите <Enter> для завешения программы");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Собирайте все слова в коллекцию, при добавление делайте `.Trim()` (в случае если пробел будет введен человеком). Ну а в конце делайте `var result = string.Join(" ", коллекция);`

Comment: Не забывайте отмечать полезные ответы галочкой. Зайдите к себе в профиль и проверьте ответы на все ваши прошлые вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня как-то так получилось. Заменил `string.Concat` на `string.Join`.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Каждая введенная вами строка "
        + "будет добавляться в предложение, "
        + "пока вы не введете EXIT или QUIT");
     
    string sentence = string.Empty;
    string[] terms = { "exit", "quit" };
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите строку");
        string line = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        if (terms.Contains(line.ToLower()))
        {
            break;
        }        
        sentence = string.Join(" ", sentence, line);
        Console.WriteLine("\nВы ввели: " + sentence);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nПолучилось:\n" + sentence);
    Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для завешения программы");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!